# What does the "work done" $\frac{dW}{dt}$ in Poynting's theorem mean? Real life examples?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I found an old Related Question here: [Can electric and magnetic forces act on their sources?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390029/can-electric-and-magnetic-forces-act-on-their-sources)

---

From the paragraph from Griffith's E&M

> Suppose we have some charge and current configuration which, at time t, produces fields $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$. In the next instant, $dt$, the charges move around a bit. According to the Lorentz force law, the **work done** on a charge $q$ is:
> \begin{split}
> dW=\mathbf F \cdot dl &=q(\mathbf E + \mathbf v \times \mathbf B) \cdot \mathbf dl\\
> \end{split}
> Poynting’s Theorem writes:
> $$dW = - d\left[ {\int {\frac{1}{2}\left( {{\varepsilon _0}{E^2} + \frac{1}{{{\mu _0}}}{B^2}} \right)} d\tau } \right] - \left[ {\oint\limits_S {\frac{{\left( {E \times B} \right)}}{{{\mu _0}}}} da} \right]dt$$

---

I am thinking of an ideal chemical battery which keeps producing EM field to charges stored inside of the battery so the charges in the cofiguration (battery) will move by $dl$.

But in this case, since the field inside of the battery is constant, the first term (inward term) in poynting's theorem equals to zero
$$
- d\left[ {\int {\frac{1}{2}\left( {{\varepsilon _0}{E^2} + \frac{1}{{{\mu _0}}}{B^2}} \right)} d\tau } \right]=0
$$

---

So what does it mean by saying the $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ field produced by charge/current configuration does work to the charges inside configuration itself?

What are some real examples of this **work done** on the charges in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does it mean by saying the  and  field produced by charge/current configuration does work to the charges inside configuration itself?

You have this backward. Inside the battery, at least at the electrodes, the matter does work on the fields. Chemical energy from the matter is converted into electromagnetic field energy. Note that the E field is from the positive to the negative terminal, but the current is from the negative to the positive terminal. So the work is negative, meaning energy is leaving the matter.

Now, as you mention, the EM field density is constant. So all of the work goes directly into EM flux. The E field points from positive to negative terminal and the B field is circumferentially around the battery so that the Poynting vector points outward. This leads to a steady conversion of chemical energy to EM energy and a steady flux of that energy out of the battery, which is indeed what happens.

Comment: So if the field keeps changing in the battery (for example, if the battery's voltage drops from 1.5v to 1.3v after a while like a real life battery). Then the term $$- d\left[ {\int {\frac{1}{2}\left( {{\varepsilon _0}{E^2} + \frac{1}{{{\mu _0}}}{B^2}} \right)} d\tau } \right]$$ becomes none zero (in this case it is positive since the field is decreasing). While the poynting vector term $$-\left[{\oint\limits_S {\frac{{\left( {E \times B} \right)}}{{{\mu _0}}}} da}\right]$$ will be a time dependent function, am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest case to understand is Joule heating in either a resistor or the electrolyte of a battery (which behaves as a resistor). In both cases the flux of the Poynting vector is inward, as you can see if you sketch the field directions. So energy comes from elsewhere: the battery in the case of a resistor, or the double layers near the battery electrodes in the case of the electrolyte (internal resistance). The electric field does work, which is converted to thermal energy. Is that what you're asking about?